# recognizing control characters 

Tags: c, linux, control-characters

On my Linux box it shows up as `^A`, `CTRL-A` when i `vi` the file. While writing a C program, how should i reference it? How can i find out a numeric value of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control characters are 0x40 less than their character. `A` is `65`, so `^A` is `1`.

Comment: Actually, it’s not minus 0x40, but xor: consider ^? as DEL.

Answer (score 0):

This should help?

http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Otherwise, you could always just read in the file and output that particular char as a value to see what it is.